# How do you change the launcher arguments for Processing.exe?

Tags: java, jvm, processing, jvm-arguments

How do I change the Launcher args when I open processsing.exe?  I'm running on a 64-bit Windows System and I need to be able to run the JVM in 32-bit mode.

```
CmdLine:    C:\dev\libs\processing-1.2.1\processing.exe --l4j-debug
WOW64:      yes
Working dir:    C:\dev\libs\processing-1.2.1\.
Bundled JRE:    java
Check launcher: C:\dev\libs\processing-1.2.1\java\bin\javaw.exe (n/a)
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit...
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6.0_21
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6.0_22
Using 64-bit runtime.
Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
Add classpath:  lib\pde.jar
Add classpath:  lib\core.jar
Add classpath:  lib\jna.jar
Add classpath:  lib\ecj.jar
Add classpath:  lib\antlr.jar
Add classpath:  lib\ant.jar
Add classpath:  lib\ant-launcher.jar
Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javaw.exe
Launcher args:  -Xms128m -Xmx128m -classpath "lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\lib\tools.jar;lib\pde.jar;lib\core.jar;lib\jna.jar;lib\ecj.jar;lib\antlr.jar;lib\ant.jar;lib\ant-launcher.jar" processing.app.Base
Args length:    198/32768 chars
Exit code:  259
```

Comment: My huntch is that it's specified in the perferences.txt file, but I'm not sure what property it's looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -iR "ant-launcher.jar" *
```

in your program's folder (C:\dev\libs\processing-1.2.1) should be enough to find out where these arguments are located. Don't have grep for Windows? Get it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, at best a hint on how to find the answer.